# Create a paypal webhook for PayPal.me payments

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to create a paypal webhook to hit my flask server. But can't seem to get the webhook part going. Does anyone know what the event is for paypal.me payments? Or if I can even make a webhook for receving direct payment to my account?

I'm trying to build a paypal webhook to post to my server when I recieve a payment.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal.me payments are not associated with a REST app/client id

The only thing that will generate webhook events for payments not associated with a REST app/client id is at the bottom of the [live Apps & Credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/live) list, under "NVP/SOAP API Apps" -> Manage Webhooks.

Comment: So are there no ways to get webhook notifications when payments are sent to my account? @preston-phx

Comment: See the second part of the answer

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more